# Check if point is on line in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, math, line

I have drawn a line and then a point, and then I want to check if the point is on the line or not. I have taken a line coordinate in array (as there was more than one line). I want to check the current point in on the last line or not?

```
if (positionX1 == positionX2 && positionY1 == positionY2) {
    float m = line.getSlope(
        drawLines[currentLines - 1][2], drawLines[currentLines - 1][3],
        drawLines[currentLines - 1][0], drawLines[currentLines - 1][1]);
    m = Float.parseFloat(df.format(m));
    float c = line.getIntercept(
        drawLines[currentLines - 1][2], drawLines[currentLines - 1][3],
        drawLines[currentLines - 1][0], drawLines[currentLines - 1][1]);
    c = Math.round(c);
    m1 = line.getSlope(positionX2, positionY2,
        drawLines[currentLines - 1][0], drawLines[currentLines - 1][1]);
    m1 = Float.parseFloat(df.format(m1));
    System.out.println(m + "   " + m1);
    c1 = line.getIntercept(positionX2, positionY2,
        drawLines[currentLines - 1][0], drawLines[currentLines - 1][1]);
    c1 = Math.round(c1);

    if (m == m1 && ((c == c1) || (c == c1 - 1) || (c == c1 + 1))) {
        System.out.println("Point is on Line");
    }
}
```

Problem is when a point is near the starting point of line or when a line is about vertical values of m1 and c1 changes with big difference. So, there's a problem for detecting if a point on line or not. How can I check for this situation?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you considered using Java's Point class? Might help make your code easier to take in.

Comment: In regards for c1 and m1 having big changes when the line approaches vertical, this is because the slope approaches infinity and the intercept becomes nonsensical, so it no longer makes sense to discuss those values.

Comment: In mathemathical terms: if ((x-x1)/(x2-x1)=(y-y1)/(y2-y1)) where p(x,y) is the point to test and (x1,y1), (x2,y2) are the edges of the line (or whatever 2 points of the line) then p is on the line (or something like this...). you might wanna include an error when comparing those using java code...

Comment: @TomElliott: how can i do that? Is there any method from which i can check?

Comment: @user1167744 The point class is just a useful class for representing x,y coordinates: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html Which would avoid having separate variables for x and y. Just cleans things up, afraid it won't offer any additional methods to help with your problem.

Comment: @user1167744 : Check this link out, [POINT IS ON LINE](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/game-programming/105959-need-fast-way-check-if-point-within-line.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Line2D.ptSegDist(x1, y1, x2, y2, xP, yP)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptSegDist-double-double-double-double-double-double-) returns 0.0 if the point (xP, yP) is on the line segment from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2).  `Line2D.ptLineDist` does the same thing for the infinite line.

Comment: Update: my original statement wasn't quite correct.  Use `ptSegDist` to check if a point is on a line _segment_, and `ptLineDist` to check if a point is on a line.

Comment: I want to check if the point was on the line or not... and your original statement was helpful to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the vector form of the [distance from a point to a line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) where the line is **x** = **a** + *t* **n**.

If instead of a unit vector **n** you use a non-unit vector **N**, then *d* = ||(**a** - **p**) - ((**a** - **p**) · **N**) **N** / ( **N** · **N**) ||, which eliminates a square root.

Assuming that the arrays of floats you are using to describe lines are interpreted as { x1, y1, x2, y2 }, then **a** = ( x1, y1 ) and **N** = ( x2 - x1, y2 - y1 ).

If the calculated distance is comparable to the measurement or arithmetic errors, the point is on the line. Again, you don't need to calculate the square root in the modulus but can compare the squared value.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of an algorithm, a line (other than one which is vertical which has equation like x = constant) has a form y = mx + b. If your point satisfies that equation, then it is on the line. So all you need to is find the slope value of the line, and its y-intercept and check to see if the point's x and y values satisfy the equation for each line.

EDIT:

As is pointed out in an above comment, you could use the point-slope form (with slope being (y2-y1)/(x2/x1)) instead of the slope-intercept form. This would give you an equation that depends solely on y,x and the start and end points of the lines which would be much easier to code out (since you define a line by its start and end points, at least in swing). The only reason I suggested the slope-intercept form was because you were already attempting to use it in your algorithm.

Comment: that is what i have done in my problem? but what to do for the above situation?

Comment: Well I answered why it is not working for the vertical line case in a comment. A vertical line is not a function, so cannot be represented as such. In terms of the other problem, it probably has to do with the rounding you are doing. I would advise using a comparison system more similar to comparing floats (i.e. if x1 - x2 < .00001 instead of if x1 = x2 ) to be a little more lenient with edge cases.